# How to set internal path to DownloadManager in android

Tags: android

I want to have a method that if SD CARD is Avaiable returns it's path if it is not returns internal storage path and use this path for below download manager.

```
DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
```

How should I do it?

Comment: You can not use internal storage for `DownloadManager`

Comment: Is there any good DownloadManager Library for android to save files in internal storage? When I use this it causes Exception in some phones